# How do I transfer my data from my xbox 360 S to xbox 360 S?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

Is it possible, if I have a 4gb S, to put my new hard drive in the 4gb S and copy the data over to the new hard drive just like a usb, then plug it into my new xbox?

Or can I just put the new hard drive in the old 4gb xbox 360 S, copy the data over, and keep the hard drive in the old xbox without anything going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The 4GB is like a flash drive that's embedded into the machine. You SHOULD be able to plug in your hard drive then transfer the content from the 4GB to the 250GB or whatever.

[More Info Here](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/storage)

System -> Settings -> Memory -> "Y" -> Transfer Content

I believe was the process.